# О поговорке "два сапога пара"

Tags: семантика, пословицы

***Два сапога пара*** — Разг. Ирон. Один другого не лучше; по своим качествам похожи друг на друга.

А если так: **Два сапога пара... да оба левые.**  Что это значит?

И какой вариант является истинным?

Comment: Если говорить о самостоятельной фразе "два сапога пара", то это никак не пословица. Скорее, поговорка.

Comment: Пришлось ознакомиться с темой http://pro-poslovicy.ru/poslovica-i-pogovorka-v-chem-raznica/  А в полном виде это пословица или поговорка?  "Филологическая наука четко проводит грань между пословицей и поговоркой, но признает то, что в живой речи пословицы могут трансформироваться в поговорки, а поговорка может дорасти до пословицы". Вот и интересно: доросла поговорка до пословицы или нет?

Comment: Думаю, и в полном виде это поговорка. Нет поучения, морали, только констатация факта.

Comment: Один в поле не воин - это тоже констатация факта, вывод самим надо делать. Здесь скорее  негативная эмоциональная оценка. С другой стороны, в этой поговорке можно  найти такую мораль: Люди могут быть похожи (дружны) не только в хорошем, но и в плохом, то есть не всегда дружба - это хорошо.

Comment: Один в поле не воин — это мнение, а не констатация факта,  другое дело факты: "в поле стоит воин" или "вот два сапога, оба левые" .

Comment: Я к тому, что в приведенном мною источнике "Один в поле не воин" - это пословица, а скрытую мораль  можно найти в любом крылатом изречении. Вот и получается не очень четкая грань у филологической науки, а несколько размытая.

Comment: И я о том, что "Один в поле не воин" - это пословица (это мнение, то есть поучение, мораль). Может, есть спорные моменты, но тут все ясно, как мне кажется.

Comment: Ну хорошо, спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В полном виде поговорка выглядит так:

[«Два сапога — пара, да оба на левую ногу надеты».](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)

*неодобр.* о ком-либо похожем друг на друга по каким-либо качествам, свойствам, положению; часто о сходстве каких-либо отрицательных черт ◆ *Два сапога ― пара: оба бредят высшими вопросами и совершенно довольны друг другом.* Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк, «Приваловские миллионы», 1883 г. ◆ *Там он особенно сошёлся с Фирсиным: по пылкости характера это были два сапога пара.* В. М. Чернов, «Записки социалиста революционера», 1922 г. ◆ *Они с нашим Корнеевым ― два сапога пара, оба без царя в голове.* Влада Валеева, «Скорая помощь», 2002 г.

---

> Два сапога пара — так говорят о двух людях, которые по тем или иным
>   соображениям не являются обычными, что делает их идеальными партнерами.
>   Таким сходством могут служить вредные привычки, не
>   совсем типичные увлечения и даже ненормальный стиль жизни.
>
> Что касается второй части поговорки: «...да оба на левую ногу надеты», то
>   это прямая отсылка к необычности этого союза. Автор хотел подчеркнуть
>   для читателя, что именно эти «два сапога» являются не совсем
>   нормальными, поэтому и надеты неправильно.
>
> Поговорка хорошо иллюстрирует брак или же просто союз двух людей,
>   которых либо отвергает, либо остерегается общество.

Другой источник говорит, что дословно так: *[Два сапога пара [да оба левые]](https://masterok.livejournal.com/1361048.html)*, то есть, имхо, куда ни кинь - всюду клин: нехорошая етая пара, как тая квартира.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, особенно за объяснение концовки "да оба левые". В этом случае  неодобрительный характер пословицы более ясен.

Answer (score 0):

«Два сапога пара» буквально означает зеркальное тожество чего-либо. Пример: парный счёт, действия с чётными и нечётными числами, где на первых порах незаменимым инструментом человеку служили его руки — левая и правая, и из них одна назначалась носителем «чётных» или «нечётных» пальцев. Только совмещая ладони физически или умозрительно, получали пару, например, из двух указательных пальцев. И понятно, что два пальца одной руки по определению не могут быть парой: *оба левые* — это не про пару.

Предложенный вариант — «Два сапога пара... да оба левые» — есть предположение отсутствия гармоничности отношений, близкой их развязки.